# NameError - uninitialized constant while running dev server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, foreman

I can't use constants that I put under config/initializers/constants.rb while running Sinatra app using foreman, or rails server.

App doesn't seem to see them throwing this at me:

```
 NameError - uninitialized constant UserJson::API_DATE_FORMAT:
```

Can I somehow force to reload them?

EDIT:
Here is the class that fails:

```
require 'active_record'

    class UserJson

      attr_accessor :id, :active, :created_at, :updated_at, :name, :email

      def self.private_json(user)
        json = UserJson.new()
        json.id = user.id
        json.active = user.active
        json.email = user.email
        json.name = user.name
        json.updated_at = user.updated_at.strftime(API_DATE_FORMAT)
        json.created_at = user.created_at.strftime(API_DATE_FORMAT)
        json
      end

    end
```

It's under app/models/user.rb. I got more classes there, and each is failing when trying to read one of the constants declared in the file with API_DATE_FORMAT

Comment: have you restarted the server?

Comment: After every change I just kill its process and run foreman start command to rerun it

Comment: where do you delcare API_DATE_FORMAT?

Comment: config/initializers/constants.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update/add anything under `config` directory you should restart the server since changes are not automatically loaded within this folder.

Another reason could be the constants resolution issue:

try

```
json.created_at = user.created_at.strftime(::API_DATE_FORMAT)
```

## EDIT

You could require the file with constants in the model:

```
 require_relative 'config/initializers/constants'
```

But since you have multiple models where you use these constants, I would try to solve it globally.

Adding the require to the main application file will make sure you do not have to require the file in each model, but only once:

```
# collector.rb (Sinatra input file)
require_relative 'config/initializers/constants'
```

Comment: I did restart the server by killing it and restarting with foreman start command

Comment: please post the code, where you use `API_DATE_FORMAT` constant

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but that didn't help

Comment: @JacekKwiecień how come? what was the error? Is the problem still actual?

Comment: It's still the same, problem at line json.updated_at = user.updated_at.strftime(::API_DATE_FORMAT)

Comment: @JacekKwiecień If `constants.rb` is a class or a module, called, say, `Constants` you should reference its constant with `Constants::API_DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: actually it's a plain text file only containing one line: 
API_DATE_FORMAT ||= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

Comment: why would you store plain text in `.rb` file? :) I would put in into `secrets.yml` or `settings.yml`, and then use like `Rails.application.settings.api_date_format`

Comment: read that's the recomended way to create globally accessible constant

Comment: do I have to add some require to use Rails?

Comment: I think it should be accessible throughout the app

Comment: it doesnt see Rails either :/

Comment: I think your idea with constants.rb is good. Just wrap the code in module, and try to reference the constant as i suggested previously

Comment: then I get NameError - uninitialized constant UserJson::Constants:

Comment: it doesnt seem to see anything from that constants.rb file

Comment: yeah did that right away but then just: NameError - uninitialized constant Constants:

Comment: Did you try `require 'config/initializers/constants'`? This would be rediculous, but to try..

Comment: yes but then server wont start: kernel_require.rb:121:in `require': cannot load such file -- config/initializers/constants (LoadError)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102263/discussion-between-jacek-kwiecien-and-andrey-deineko).

Comment: I'll be near computer a bit later then ill visit the chat, ok?